# Extremely large reconstruction errors in NMF

Tags: audio, spectrogram, source-separation

First time in this stack...
I am doing some audio analysis. I have a spectrogram ($N\approx 33000, M=1024$) and I need to run an NMF algorithm on it. I am using the [Scikit learn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html). And [the code on Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py#L808).

- Immediately, what strikes me strange, is if you look at the `fit_transform` functions, the returned signal representation is called `W`, which makes me believe that the dictionary learned is our `H`. Aren't the naming conventions for these two components the opposite?
- Second, my reconstruction error is in the thousands. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

My spectrogram is non negative, as required.

Comment: Depending on how your spectrogram is scaled, "thousands" may not be as bad as you think it is. What's the error, if normalized by the total energy in your spectrogram? How many components did you choose when decomposing?

Comment: I am using 150 components. Is normalizing the spectrogram common practice for the NMF?

Comment: Perhaps, your audio signal is very "rich" and isn't well represented by 150 components. How does the error of "thousands" compare to the total energy in your spectrogram? i.e. what is $||X-WH||^2/||X||^2$?

Comment: I will do the computation as soon as I get home. Intuitively, what is it we are looking for in this normalization?

Comment: Also, do you think the row dimension of ~33k is way too large for 150 components and I should reduce the sampling frequency?

Comment: Seriousness of the reconstruction error is relative to what you are trying to measure or reconstruct. In this case, the absolute error number of 1000 doesn't tell us much, unless we normalize it by the "size" of the original spectrogram. eg. an error of 1000 in one million is tiny, but an error of 1000 in 10,000 is large and worth worrying about.

Comment: Choice of sampling frequency should be primarily driven by Nyquist considerations, not by the choice of #components for NMF.

Comment: I was under the impression that reconstruction error is the Frobenious norm of X - WH, which means it should tend to 0 if the reconstruction is accurate.

Comment: Mathematically, you are absolutely right. But practically, an error of 1000 in something that's a million big is basically "zero" :)

Comment: Ah...makes sense :) Lastly, if the spectrogram is 33k by 1024 matrix and i pick 150 components, the dictionary H should be 150 by 1024 correct? Or is the dictionary the W (33k by 150 matrix)?

Comment: The columns of $W$ make the dictionary. If your original spectrogram $X$ is $33k \times 1024$ and you choose to keep 150 components, then you are decomposing $X \approx WH$ where $W$ is $33k \times 150$ and $H$ is $150 \times 1024$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decompose $X \approx WH$, the columns of $W$ form the dictionary and the columns of $H$ are the time varying weights. In your example, if you choose 150 components, then $W$ should be $33k \times 150$ and $H$ should be $150 \times 1024$.

The error "in thousands" could mean one of two things:

1. It's practically "zero" if you normalize it by the Frobenius norm of the spectrogram $X$, in which case all is well, or,
2. Perhaps your sound signal is too rich to be completely representable by 150 components and you should experiment by increasing that number.

It is also worth noting that squared error is often not a good measure for audio perception. Two signals with a large squared difference may sound almost the same.

Comment: By the way, the relative error is 0.087